# How to draw a path with coordinates defined by f(x)

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I'm writing about fixed point and I would like to do this image in tikz without the labels.

[image]

Is there any way to define a function `f` such `x --> x*(4-x)` and a recursion

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,4) -- (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:4] plot(\x,{(\x)*(4.0-(\x))});
\draw[dotted,->] (0.04,0) -- (0.04,f(0.04));
\foreach n \in {1,2,3,4,5}
\draw[dotted,->] (f^n(0.04),f^{n+1}(0.04))--(f^{n+1}(0.04),f^{n+1}(0.04)); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Edit** Thanks to Andrew for the correction in the function f.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathparse` (or `\pgfmathsetmacro` as below) to recursively compute your function as you run through the pgf `\foreach` loop. of course, you need to "save" the previous value as you go.

Your question seems to be using both the functions `x(4-x)` and `x(4-x)/2`, so I have stuck with the first one. It's very sensitive on the initial value of course:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{% style to put arrow head in middle of line
  ->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
              postaction={decorate}},
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thin,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
    \draw[thin,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (4,4);
    \draw[blue,thick,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:4] plot(\x,{(\x)*(4.0-(\x))});
    \def\fn{0.2}% initial value
    \draw[dashed](\fn,0)node[below=1mm]{$\fn$}--(\fn,\fn);
    \foreach \n in {1,...,8} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\fnn{\fn*(4-\fn)}% compute the next value
      \draw[dotted,->-](\fn,\fn)--(\fn,\fnn);
      \draw[dotted,->-](\fn,\fnn)--(\fnn,\fnn);
      \xdef\fn{\fnn}% save value - need \xdef to force expansion
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, so sorry, I'm going to edit, it is only x*(4-x)

Comment: @LuisFelipe I just noticed your arrow heads were centered so I have added this.

Comment: wirh some math, the image is better for f(x)=2.7*x*(1-x) for 0<x<1 and for fn=0.04